# Is there a way to manage switching between multiple Docker hosts

Tags: docker

I've just set up a remote Docker host on a spare laptop I have and I'm able to access it by doing

```
docker -H 192.168.1.201 run hello-world
```

but I don't want to keep adding -H every time I want to run an image on remote, nor do I want to set DOCKER_HOST via environment variable as I'm planning on setting up another remote host on a DO Droplet.

Is there a way to switch between active Docker hosts the same way you'd switch Python versions with pyenv? (or nodenv, rbenv, or equivalent..)

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
docker switch-host laptop
```

and it'd automatically set DOCKER_HOST to point to my laptop's IP, and maybe

```
docker switch-host local
```

and we're back to running containers on the local machine.

For reference, the remote host I've set up is on an Ubuntu VM inside of a Windows 10 laptop, while the "client" is Ubuntu 18.04 through WSL on a Windows 10 desktop.

Comment: Look into `docker-machine`, it could possibly solve your issue completely.

Comment: ... or, why not just source a file that sets the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable? That's directly comparable to your `docker switch-host ${HOST}` example, and could be wrapped up in a bash function or similar.

Comment: @gronostaj I was under the impression that docker-machine is obsolete now.

Comment: @Attie to be honest that hadn't crossed my mind. Lockdown's got me moving slower than I usually do :-(

Answer (score 0):

Bash script to change DOCKER_HOST

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to set DOCKER_HOST variable to list, otherwise unset
# run by "source <script_name> <option>" or ". <script_name> <option>"

case $1 in
    "laptop") DOCKER_HOST=192.168.1.1;;
    "droplet") DOCKER_HOST=10.1.1.1;;
    *) unset DOCKER_HOST
esac
```

Comment: That won't work unless "sourced", and if sourced the shebang isn't necessary, so putting  a shebang is misleading.

Comment: Agreed totally - that is addressed in the second line of the directions comment.